# Pronunciation of "жёлтый"

Tags: произношение

I thought that ё was always stressed, but in the word жёлтый its pronounced ZHOL-tiy, if this is right then when  is ё unstressed? Is it because of palatalization? Thank you in advance

Comment: And also how important are voices and unvoiced consonants when a russian is listening to you, i am learning them but i would love to know

Comment: the transcription is correct, in the word **жёлтый** **Ё** is indeed stressed,  there're principles of voicing and unvoicing which need to be adhered to, the only sure case where the distinction between voiced and unvoiced consonants doesn't affect intellegibility of a word is at the final position in a word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Жёлтый is pronounced as [жолтый], so `ё` here stands for `o`.  The reason why it is the case is actually that `ё` wherever right after consonant just indicates that that particular consonant is palatalized. In some cases this give an illusion that `ё` is a sound sort of similar to the german `ö` - this happens for instance in `тёмный`. However, it's not the case.

But `ж` in modern Russian is never softened, so words like `жёлтый`, `жёлудь`, `жёваный`, `жёсткий`, `жёны` are pronounced as `жо-` - and there's no even slightest trace of ö-illusion one might get with soft consonants. By the way, same story with `ш`, so `шёпот` is actually pronounced `шопот`.

And actually in this case `ё` is stressed - almost like always except some foreign words like `сёрфинги́сты` and some very exotic exceptions in compound words like `четырёхчастный`, `трёхчастный` etc.

Comment: Does this rule also work for я , ю, and е? I cross out the first part of the letter so in yu , i would remove the y and it would just be the english u?

Comment: So the rule would be я, ё, ю, and е after a consonant would remove the first part of the sound “y”[j]

Comment: @Almonds812 well, it's slightly more complicated but generally you got the idea right

Comment: Yep i got it man , thanks so much for the help  i was so confused